# Comments when rejecting an edit

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

I just rejected a proposed edit that added a significant sentence to the post.  I would have liked to leave a comment to that effect, but didn't have the option as I selected "radical edit" as the reason for rejection.  It seems easy to let the comment box be optional for all rejects or even accepts.

Comment: I've had the same experience, but I suspect the developers' intention was that the canned rejection reasons are simply there as a help to avoid too much typing in simple cases -- in other words, that you're free to copy-paste one of the canned explanations into the free-form reason field and then add whatever you like to it there.